# parseInt() returns NaN instead of integer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a route-finder using javascript. To do so, I create a grid from a 2d array, and insert 'x' (walls), 'o' (open space), '0' (start), and 'g' (goal). I would like to increment the open squares from the start to the goal, so I end up with something that looks like this: '0',1,2,3,4,5 ... g

However, my grid never goes past 0 and 1. My console keeps returning NaN for the remaining open spaces and I suspect it's a typeError from using parseInt(). Please see my code below - I really appreciate your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href = 'routes.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
<script>
//o is an open space x is a wall
var a = [['0','o','x','x'], 
         ['x','o','o','o'],
         ['x','o','x','o'],
         ['x','o','o','g']];

    /*printed grid looks like this
var a = [[0,1,'x','x'], 
         ['x',NaN,NaN,NaN],
         ['x',NaN,'x',NaN],
         ['x',NaN,NaN,'g']];*/


function move(startR,startC){ //(0,0) startR,startC
    var north = startR-1; 
    var south = startR+1;
    var east = startC+1;
    var west = startC-1;

    //discard all the out of bounds locations
    if (north<0){north=startR;}
    if (south>3){south=startR;}
    if (east>3){east=startC;}
    if (west<0){west=startC;}


    if (a[north][startC]=='o'){newLocation(north,startC,startR,startC);}
    if (a[south][startC]=='o'){newLocation(south,startC,startR,startC);}
    if (a[startR][west]=='o'){newLocation(startR,west,startR,startC);}
    if (a[startR][east]=='o'){newLocation(startR,east,startR,startC);}

}
//newLocation() increments square I just moved to and pass the new location to the function 'move '

function newLocation(northSouth,eastWest,origR,origC){

    var origValue = parseInt(a[origR,origC]);
    console.log(origValue); //prints NaN to console
    var newValue = ++origValue;
    a[northSouth][eastWest]=newValue;
    console.log(a[origR,origC]);
    return move(northSouth,eastWest);
}

move(0,0);

//print board to screen

for (r=0;r<4;r++){
    document.write('<br>');
    for (c=0;c<4;c++){
        var l = document.createElement('div');
        var t = document.createTextNode(a[r][c]);
        $(l).addClass('letterboxes');
        l.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(l);
//      document.body.appendChild(letter);
    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `a[origR,origC]` is not how you index into nested arrays. `a[origR,origC]` is equivalent to `a[origC]`. To access the nested array you'd write `a[origR][origC]` (which you seem to know because earlier you are doing `a[north][startC]`). But it's unclear to me what you want to achieve with `parseInt` here. What do you expect `parseInt('x')` or `parseInt('o')` to return?

Comment: thank you, it works now with a[origR][origC], curious how it managed to increment 0 to 1 and print it out if the indexing was off? parseInt() only converts integer stored as newValue in newLocation()

Comment: You basically did `parseInt(a[0])`, which is `parseInt(['0','o','x','x']`), which is `parseInt('0,o,x,x')` which returns `0` (because of how `parseInt` works). However, why do you store numbers as strings in the first place? No need for `parseInt` if you store numbers.

Comment: all right ill try storing numbers in array. I wasn't sure whether it was OK to mix different types in an array

Comment: It's ok. And you are already mixing types anyway: `a[northSouth][eastWest]=newValue;` assigns a number to that position in the array.